# Why won't list items align at bottom of containing element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have some links align at the bottom of their containing element. I added vertical-align text-bottom to the containing element. I get nothing.

Here is the contents in the main html file.

```
 <div class="mainHeader">

 <li><a class="mainHeaderLink" href="book.html">BOOK A ROOM</a></li>
 <li><a class="mainHeaderLink" href="promotions.html">PROMOTIONS</a></li>
 <li><a class="mainHeaderLink" href="meetings.html">MEETINGS & EVENTS</a></li>
 <li><a class="mainHeaderLink" href="about.html">ABOUT STIL</a></li>

 </div>
```

Here is my css file. (the css works, just not the align property)

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


body 
{
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}


div.mainHeader
{
background-color: #006;
background: solid;
height:100px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: text-bottom;
 }


 a.mainHeaderLink:link
 {
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }

 a.mainHeaderLink:visited
 {
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 16px;
 }

 a.mainHeaderLink: active
 {
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #CCC;
font-size: 16px;
 }

 a.mainHeaderLink:hover
 {
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #CCC;
font-size: 16px;
 }

 li
 {
display:inline;
margin-left: 50px;

 }
```

Comment: Vertical-align goes on either inline or table-cell elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have said, put your `<li>` items inside a `<ul>` tag.  Given the css above you can 'center' your menu items with this change to your css:

```
li
 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top:37px;
 }
```

[check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/KTfj3/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid to have `<li>` without a `<ul>` parent.  Fix that.

Additionally, I would just add a couple of simple styles to get it to "align" to the bottom rather than mess around with `vertical-align`, which I believe to be [cursed](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

```
.mainHeader {
    position: relative;
}
.mainHeader ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3SFz/

Comment: Thanks. But not it doesn't allow the links to center align?